# Purchase Order - Supplier Code

Tags: odoo-10

I am trying to get Supplier code to show on the Purchase order.

I am able to make it show, as long as there is only a single vendor associated with the product, but if there is more I get the error: `Unexpected singleton`

```
<xpath expr="//table[@class='table table-condensed']//tbody//tr" position="replace">
  <td>
    <span t-f="line.product_id.seller_ids.product_code"/>
  </td>
</xpath>
```

Is there a way to get the default or first seller code to show, if there is more than 2 vendors on the product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the simple way, using **and** operator.

Ex:

```
    <xpath expr="//table[@class='table table-condensed']//tbody//tr" position="replace">
      <td>
        <span t-field="line.product_id.seller_ids and line.product_id.seller_ids[0].product_code"/>
      </td>
    </xpath>
```